# How to use Azure.ResourceManager.CostManagement to get Azure subscription daily detailed costs

Tags: c#, .net, azure, sdk

I've searched the internet extensively and couldn't find a single example for Azure.ResourceManager.CostManagement .NET SDK that shows how to get costs.

I need this to get daily azure subscription detailed costs.

Comment: if you tried with any code or any approach ,can you please share

Answer (score 0):

***I tried below code and received the successful output like below:-***

```c
using Microsoft.Rest.Azure.Authentication;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Consumption;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Consumption.Models;
using Microsoft.Rest.Azure;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string tenantId = "xxxxxx5";
        string clientId = "xxxxxx35cb";
        string clientSecret = "xxxxxx8dkdBH";
        string subscriptionId = "xxxxxxb2a7";

        var serviceClientCredentials = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret).Result;

        var consumptionManagementClient = new ConsumptionManagementClient(serviceClientCredentials)
        {
            SubscriptionId = subscriptionId
        };

        // Get the first and last day of the current month
        var firstDayOfMonth = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1);
        var lastDayOfMonth = firstDayOfMonth.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);

        // Create a filter to get the usage details for the current month
        var filter = $"properties/usageStart ge '{firstDayOfMonth}' and properties/usageEnd le '{lastDayOfMonth}'";


        // Get the usage details for the current month
        var dailyCosts = new List<UsageDetail>();

        IPage<UsageDetail> usageDetails = await consumptionManagementClient.UsageDetails.ListAsync(filter: filter);

        dailyCosts.AddRange(usageDetails);

        foreach (var usageDetail in dailyCosts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{usageDetail.UsageStart}: {usageDetail.PretaxCost}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine(dailyCosts.Sum(x => x.PretaxCost));
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(
            $"Total cost for the current month: {dailyCosts.Sum(x => x.PretaxCost)}");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

**Output:-**

[image]